# Hover over shortened text to expand without affecting surrounding elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an element that I have set `text-overflow: ellipsis`. I then set a hover to expand the text. Is there a way in CSS to eliminate the expanded text from affecting elements above it or below it?

Setting the text:

```
.box h3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box h3:hover {
  text-overflow: initial;
  white-space: normal;
  background-color:blue;
  display: block;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMoxyr)

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly setting a width to the box element, which is why it's causing the height of the box to increase.

The css is trying to fill the box with the new content, but it can't make the box bigger widthways, so it must expand heightways.

Comment: No, I realize that. I was just seeing if there was some way around from keeping it moving. Some positional call that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it (hover state) position: absolute (position it correctly in page) and opaque IT in div with higher z-index that element that should be below (i'm not sure at the moment is that even required).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have the desired effect: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xdbvex

Set the `.box` to `position:relative` and the `h3:hover` to `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the current layout, when you hover the new characters fill the box forcing it to expand in height as there is no more room width wise due to the width restriction.

Without using any javascript you would have to lift the element you are hovering over from the dom using an absolute positioning.

However this will result in the element under it lift up the page which is what you don't want.

It's a tricky one without javascript and I cannot think of a way without duplicating content on the screen. But this works, could do with some tidying up though :)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.box {
  width: 170px;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.box h3 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper:hover > .hidden {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Really long text that will wrap</h3>
    <div class="hidden">Really long text that will wrap</div>
  </div>
  <h2>Text Below its dfg asdrg sdh zxdh xcgh .</h2>
</div>
```